# How to update div contents on 'onchange' event using Ajax and Codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter v3.1.3 on WAMP.In one of my view (our_districts.php), i have a dropdownlist containing district names:

```
<select class="form-control" id="ddlDist" name="ddlDist" onchange="popDistrictData();">
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option value="3">District A</option>
    <option value="4">District B</option>
    <option value="5">District C</option>
    <option value="6">District D</option>
</select>
<div id="districtData"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function popDistrictData(){
        var dist_id = document.getElementById("ddlDist").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?=site_url()?>section/ajax_call_pop_district_data/"+dist_id,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(html){
                $("#districtData").html(html);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

### Section Controller:

```
class Section extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->output->set_header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        $this->load->helper("url");
        $this->load->model("District_model");
    }
    public function view()
    {
        $data['section_name']='Districts';
        $this->load->view('templates/site_header',$data);
        $data["district_data"] = $this->District_model->pop_districts_in_combobox();
        $this->load->view('our_districts',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/site_footer',$data);   
    }

    public function ajax_call_pop_district_data()
    {
        if ($this->input->post('distId') !="") {
            $did = $_POST['distId'];
            $dist_data = $this->District_model->pop_district_data($did);
            //what should i write here???.........
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see that the above dropdownlist is getting populated by `'pop_districts_in_combobox()'` method of `'District_model'`.On its `'onchange'` event,
i want to populate the div with id=districtData using Ajax as shown above.My problem is how to fill the `div(id=districtData)` .Please help with some code.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in an ajax call, so that ajax should return the code that will process the jQuery $.ajax function.

In your jQuery success function code you're doing a simple `$("#districtData").html(html);`

So in the controller function ajax_call_pop_district_data you should do a **simple** `echo $dist_data` which should have html code generated by the model function `pop_district_data`.

Comment: OMG!.It was that easy.Thanks @NetVicious